# Solr - higher score for higher product prices

Tags: solr

I'm searching for products in my catalog using Solr. 
I wanted to know how can I give a higher score for products with higher prices?

this is the request that I'm sending:

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/collection1/query?q=iphone&rows=4&fq=price:[*+TO+500]
```

I'm getting many iPhone cases, so I want to flow up results with higher prices (To get the iPhone cellular machine), or if its possible to show 1 result for price range 0 - 50, another one for 50 - 100 etc. and that way I will be able to show few products from few categories.

Comment: fq parameters don't change the score only text search does that. I think sort should be used to get the results you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show 1 result for each price range, use [Solr Grouping](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing).

You can use a query like,

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/collection1/query?q=iphone&rows=4&group=true&group.query=price:[0 TO 50]&group.query=price:[51 TO 100]
```

If you want you can also set **group.main=true** as a parameter to get response in the normal format.

You can use **'group.limit'** parameter to limit number of results in each group.

You also have the privilege to sort within the group using **'group.sort'** parameter, in case, you need more than one result from each group in sorted order.

Answer (score 0):

use sort parameter to sort the results by price. So, the request becomes :-

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/collection1/query?q=iphone&rows=4&fq=price:[*+TO+500]&sort=price desc
```

I am not sure about showing 1 results for different price ranges but perhaps, you can use faceting to do that.

http://searchhub.org/2009/09/02/faceted-search-with-solr/